# Странное поведение call() и apply()

Tags: javascript, функции, prototype

При написании скрипта столкнулся с такой проблемой: 
В ниже прикрепленном фрагменте упрощенного кода в который я помечу нужный участок, при вызове через `apply()`, на втором прохождении появляется ошибка:

```
Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object
```

То есть первый раз он срабатывает корректно. А во втором прохождении происходит ошибка, ещё до входа в функцию. При этом, если `apply()` заменить на `call()`, то всё начинает работать корректно.
Возможно я не до конца понимаю разницу в этих методах. Вроде разница лишь в динамическом диапазон аргументов у `apply()`. Хотя возможно я что то путаю.

Был бы рад если мне пояснили причину такого поведения. Вот [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/kjyn3aqn/4/) весь код. Заранее спасибо.

```
function MetaRow(name,value){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
}

function MetaGroup(name){
    this.name = name;
    this.items = {};
    this.groups = {};
}


MetaGroup.prototype.set = function(key,meta,replace = false)
{
    if(meta instanceof MetaRow){
        //Добавляем строку
    }
    else if(meta instanceof MetaGroup){
        //Добавляем группу
    }
}

function FormMeta(forms)
{
    this.forms = forms;
    this.Global = new MetaGroup();
    FormMeta.prototype.update.apply(this);
}
FormMeta.prototype.get = function(key)
{
    return this.Global.groups[key] != undefined ? this.Global.groups[key] : this.Global.groups['main'];
}

FormMeta.prototype.pickRadio = function(form)
{
    var glob = this;
    $(form).find('radio-group').each(function(i,val){
        var targetGroup,mid,rid,rname;
        //Далее я заполняю переменные ничего интересного


        //Вот на это строке в момент вызова apply() генерируется ошибка 
        FormMeta.prototype.get.apply(glob,mid).set(rid, new MetaRow(rname),true);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp - `apply` принимает параметры вызова в виде массива:

```
FormMeta.prototype.get.apply(glob, [mid]).set(rid, new MetaRow(rname), true);
```

или

```
FormMeta.prototype.get.call(glob, mid).set(rid, new MetaRow(rname), true);
```

Comment: Хорошо. А, допустим, почему это корректно срабатывает при первом прохождении?

Comment: Вы чего-то не замечаете :). Также, дело может быть в логике кода замененного на *"//Далее я заполняю переменные ничего интересного"*. Чему, например, в результате равно `mid`?

Comment: Вроде ничего особенного: `var targetGroup = $(val).parent('meta-group').first();        
        var mid = $(targetGroup).attr('mid');`

Comment: я вижу. Тот код, который Вы привели в фидле, как он вызывается?

Comment: Возможно, из за того что он вызывался через  `call()` : `FormMeta.prototype.pickRadio.call(this,form);` . Но он вызывется 1 раз

Comment: Я не понимаю. Фидл - не рабочий? Там этой строчки нет.

Comment: А сам код запускался через `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52333/discussion-between-bwehaafox-and-igor).